# How to change ADD(+) and MINUS(-) button position in tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

**I am trying to modify the position of ADD(+ with green background color) button's position when table-view is in editing mode.**

[image]

**I have tried so many ways to modify it which are suggested in web or other stack-overflow questions. But it seems they are not working. I tried to put Custom button on that place and on that click i have tried to insert the row which Makes the app crash.**

NOTE : here Phone number is a complete separate section.

Can anyone help or guide me to solve this issue so i can put this add button  on the right side or i can change + button frame ?

Any help will be appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

first you can use custom cell which i recommend incase in future you wanted to add other views to your cells and in its nib file you can easily choice its place

the second way is to change the frame of the UIImage view in your cell

```
cell.imageView.fram = CGRectMake(x,y,width,height);
```

you can give it the x you wanted i recommend the x be equal cell.frame.size.width-(cell.imageView.size.width+10)

like that

```
cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width-(cell.imageView.size.width+10), y, width,height)
```

hope this answer can help you please let me know if you need any more help good luck